How do I remove the old style plastic sink knob?
I feel like I’m getting pretty close here.  I expected the collar to come off but it doesn’t budge.
Any idea what the next step is?
There’s a nut on the valve stem but I’m not sure I have a way to get in there.




using a deep socket wrench undo the hex nut at the base of the valve stem.

And hold the bottom with a wrench or vise grips while you work the top (or have a helper if you can't reach both simultaneously).  In a pinch you might be able to stick a long tool in the faucet side hole.
